# How to avoid Kendo Multiselect from clearing the input when focus is lost?

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-multiselect

I'm working with Kendo UI for JQuery, and I declared a multiselect to act as a TagBox following [this example](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/knowledge-base/multiselect-as-tagbox?_ga=2.240645956.651624391.1604588918-1881170541.1586281364).

I noticed that whenever the component loses its focus, whatever was typed is cleared. I wish to avoid this behavior, since forcing a user to retype whatever they had anytime they click outside the Multiselect would be annoying.

I tried to do this:

```
$('.email_notification_create .k-multiselect .k-input').unbind('blur');
$('.email_notification_create .k-multiselect .k-input').on('blur', function(){
            console.log(currentEmailInput.val());
            console.log('overriden blur');
});
```

But the value on the input is already cleared, so someone else is clearing the input when the focus is lost.

How can I stop the Multiselect from clearing its input?

Answer (score 0):

As you have already defined `function` on `keyup` you can add an else part inside it to get the last value which user has typed and store them in some global variable . Then , you  can use `focusout` event so when the input loose focus then defined some function inside that assign `values` to your input-box and change its `width` as well.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
var valuess; //declare this
var widths; //and this
var currentId = 1;

function onDataBound(e) {
  $('.k-multiselect .k-input').unbind('keyup');
  $('.k-multiselect .k-input').on('keyup', onClickEnter);
  //add this event when input lost it focus
  $('.k-multiselect .k-input').on('focusout', values);
}

function onClickEnter(e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 13) {
    var widget = $('#products').getKendoMultiSelect();
    var dataSource = widget.dataSource;
    var input = $('.k-multiselect .k-input');
    var value = input.val().trim();
    if (!value || value.length === 0) {
      return;
    }
    var newItem = {
      ProductID: currentId++,
      ProductName: value
    };

    dataSource.add(newItem);
    var newValue = newItem.ProductID;
    widget.value(widget.value().concat([newValue]));
    $('.k-multiselect .k-input').val("")
    valuess="";//empty values
  } else {
    //get the values of input and width of input
    valuess = $('.k-multiselect .k-input').val()
    widths = $('.k-multiselect .k-input').width()
  }
}
$("#products").kendoMultiSelect({
  autoClose: false,
  dataTextField: "ProductName",
  dataValueField: "ProductID",
  dataSource: {
    data: []
  },
  dataBound: onDataBound
});


function values() {
  //set width
  $('.k-multiselect .k-input').css("width", widths)
  //remove readonly from input
  $('.k-multiselect .k-input').removeClass("k-readonly")
  $('.k-widget').addClass("k-state-hover k-state-focused")
  $('.k-clear-value').removeClass("k-hidden")
  $('.k-multiselect .k-input').val(valuess) //add the values
}
```

```css
#products-list {
  display: none !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2020.3.1021/styles/kendo.common.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2020.3.1021/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2020.3.1021/styles/kendo.default.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2020.3.1021/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2020.3.1021/js/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2020.3.1021/js/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2020.3.1021/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>

<select id="products" style="width: 100%;"></select>
```